# ruby 1.8.7 installation error on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.8.7

recently I re installed Ubuntu 11.10 and was trying to set my working ruby and rails framework. But now I can not install 1.8.7 on my system. I loaded RVM successfully, i hope. The version it displays is 1.20.4. But as I proceed to install my rubies it throws error as

*No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/11.10/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p371.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.*

I have gone through so many online suggestion but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas guyz???

Also when I check the available ruby versions using *rvm list known*, it displays the list of rubies available and 1.8.7 is among one of them, then why this error appears as No binary rubies available. I need to have ruby 1.9.3 and 1.8.7.

```
kumar@Jarvis-Dell-XPS-L502X:~$ rvm install ruby-1.8.7
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.

No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/11.10/x86_64/ruby-1.8.7-p371.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary  rubies.

Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg
Hit http://it.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-updates Release.gpg

kumar@Jarvis-Dell-XPS-L502X:~$ rvm -v
rvm 1.20.4 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis       <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: I have already tried all the instructions like this sometimes even with some wiered suggestions available online...eventually ended up with the same error mentioned above..the issue comes when I run rvm install 1.8.7...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/21/set-up-an-ubuntu-local-development-machine-for-ruby-on-rails/ this tutorial guides you perfectly for your Ruby Set up on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score -1):

You can try to replace RVM with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/). Did you try rbenv before?